# Смещение содержимого блока от бордера

Tags: html, css, border

Делаю блок с постером. При наведении по макету должен появляться бордер, но не должен смещать при этом ни содержимое блока, ни увеличивать его размер.

В моём же случае, изменяется положение содержимого, сдвигается на `2px` (толщина обводки).

Попробовал `box-sizing`, не помогло.

Подскажите, возможно ли это?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Меняйте цвет бордера с transparent на нужный цвет

```css
div{
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: gray;
 border: 10px solid transparent;
 }
 
 div:hover{
  border: 10px solid red;
  }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Вариант с тенью

```css
 div{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url("http://img.clipartall.com/emotion-smiley-faces-clip-art-clipart-best-emotion-faces-clip-art-631_632.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  }

  div:hover{
   box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px red;
   }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Тогда у блока будет бордер цвета фона

Comment: А у меня там стоим изображение которое полностью заполняет блок

Comment: Тогда делайте через box-shadow, пример выше

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно свойство [`outline`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/outline)

> В отличие от линии, задаваемой через border, свойство outline не влияет на положение блока и его ширину.

```css
.test {
  background: #999;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.test:hover {
  outline: 4px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```